# how to access the onload event by C++ bho

Tags: c++, events, browser, invoke, bho

I have a problem in using the IWebBrowser. My project is that, when the user clicks button in the IE toolbar, a popup window (created by `CreateWindow` Method) is displayed. The popup window is used for displaying HTML. I use a new IWebBrowser point to display, not the point which set in the SetSite method. But I can't catch the load event from the popup window.

My bho extend IDispatch, and in the method Invoke, it can catch the load event from the website which opens in the browser not the popup window!

Is there any problem in my code? what can I do if I want to catch the load event?

Comment: Posting snippets of code might help clarify your question.